# DataTable gives error when reloading using ajax.reload()

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using jQuery to edit data in a Datatable. When the user has clicked the edit button I want the datatable to refresh without reloading the page. I have used this line of code for that:

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

However for some reason it keeps giving me the error:

> DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
> Is there any way to solve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the AJAX request working to populate the table when the page first loads? I don't see how it's possible for it to work on load, but fail on reload given that the JSON format of the response is invalid. In any case, you need to correct the JSON you return. We can't help with that as you've not shown the relevant code for us to help debug.

Comment: Your JSON is not well formated please check it first.

Comment: I found the error. My JSON was not formatted correctly. I made some slight adjustments and now it is working, Thanks a lot